# "Seinen Geburtsort besucht habe ich allerdings noch nicht."

Tags: word-order, past-participle

Der im Titel erwähnte Satz habe ich in der FAS gelesen. Wenn man das Partizip in Position 1 setzen möchte, darf bzw. muss man dessen Ergänzungen ihm voranstellen? Klingt das besser als beispielsweise

> Besucht habe ich seinen Geburtsort allerdings noch nicht.

oder sind die beiden halt gleichermaßen korrekte Variante?

Edit: Deutlichkeitshalber schreibe ich einen Teil des Abschnitts ab, in dem dieser Satz im FAS (19.05.2019, S. 10) zu lesen ist:

> Wie die meisten Neuseeländer bin auch ich über meinen Stammbaum mit Europa verbunden. Mein Großvater stammt aus Essex in England. **Seinen Geburtsort besucht habe ich allerdings noch nicht**. Vor zwölf Jahren war ich in Europa und habe einige Zeit in Deutschland verbracht. (...)

Comment: Ich kann keine Grammatikregeln zitieren, daher nur Kommentar: "S. G. besucht habe ich" referenziert den zuvor (?) besprochenen Ort und betont die Aktivität. D.h., die Stellung aus der FAS ändert die "0815"-Satzreihenfolge, um die Referenz & Betonung auf die Aktion zu legen. *Nachfrage: ist im Kontext vom GebOrt vorher die Rede?* Das eigene Beispiel setzt m.E. nur eine schwache Referenz zum vorhergehenden Gespräch, die Betonung liegt auch stark auf der Aktivität - und könnte auch im Kontext stehen, dass "sein" GebOrt unbesucht, der von anderen Leuten aber schon.

Comment: Es wäre schön, wenn der unmittelbar vorangehende Satz mitzitiert würde.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Seinen Geburtsort besucht habe ich allerdings noch nicht.

Für diejenigen, die an die Falschheit dieses Satzes glauben oder an seiner Richtigkeit zweifeln, habe ich ein Beispiel. Nehmen wir an, eine berühmte Persönlichkeit wurde in Stadt A geboren und starb in Stadt B. Dann ließe sich sagen:

> Am Grab bin ich häufig, seinen Geburtsort besucht habe ich allerdings
>   noch nicht.

Aber auch so, wie er in Zeile 1 steht, lässt sich der Satz verbauen, z. B. wenn der Sprecher eine Pause macht, weil er mit dem Schraubenzieher irgendwo herumfummelt und sich kurz anstrengen muss oder weil er zwischendurch den Kopf unter der Küchenspüle hat.

> Am Grab bin ich häufig. – Seinen Geburtsort besucht habe ich allerdings noch nicht.

---

Beide in der Frage genannten Varianten sind also korrekt; welche besser passt und klingt, entscheidet der Kontext.

Answer (score -3):

Der Satz in der FAS ist schlicht falsch. Die V2-Regel ist verletzt, denn *Seinen Geburtsort besucht* sind zwei Satzteile.

Es muss entweder

> Besucht habe ich seinen Geburtsort allerdings noch nicht.

oder

> Seinen Geburtsort habe ich allerdings noch nicht besucht.

oder

> Ich habe seinen Geburtsort allerdings noch nicht besucht.

oder

> Allerdings habe ich seinen Geburtsort noch nicht besucht.

etc. heißen. Es muss genau ein Satzteil vor dem finiten Verb stehen.

Comment: Falsch ist es nicht. *Seinen Geburtsort besucht* kann selber ein Satzteil sein. Weitere Beispiele [hier](https://hpsg.hu-berlin.de/~stefan/Pub/deutsche-syntax-deklarativ.pdf) auf S. 353 f. unter 18.1.

Comment: "Falsch" würde ich da wirklich nicht sagen. In geeignetem Kontext kann ein solcher Satz (oder ein solches Satzfragment) durchaus vorkommen, ohne als "falsch" empfunden zu werden. Einen solchen gelesen habe ich zwar selten. Einen solchen in der FAZ zu finden würde ich aber nicht für unmöglich halten. Die FAZ-Redakteure darob für dumm zu halten, fände ich vermessen.

Comment: Ist die "V2-Regel" nicht eher eine Richtlinie als ein Gesetz?

Comment: Da dort "Ich" steht, nehme ich an, dass es sich um ein Zitat handelt. (Aber ganz abgesehen davon gehe ich grundsätzlich davon aus, dass Fehler vorkommen.)

Comment: Die V2-Regel ist eine der ganz wenigen Satzbildungsregeln, die im Deutschen notorisch befolgt werden.

Comment: @David Vogt: Es liegt vermutlich an *Seinen*, dass sich mir schon beim Zuhören die Fußnägel hochbiegen. Es bindet sehr stark an *Geburtsort*. Damit fällt aber die Bindung an *besucht* schwächer aus und zumindest für mich zerfällt das ganze damit beim Hören in seine Teile.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann "Einen solchen gelesen" I see what you did there ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @Janka Wenn man auf eine Abweichung von einer sprachlichen Regel trifft, kann man sagen: "Die Regel hat eine Ausnahme" oder "Die Abweichung ist falsch". Immer wenn eine Vielzahl von kompetenten Sprecher*innen diese Abweichung vertritt, muss man die erste Aussage treffen, sonst ist der Regelbegriff ziemlich willkürlich. V2 ist eine deskriptive Aussage, keine normative. Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen